# How do I configure the log4net RemotingAppender?

Tags: log4net

How to configure remotingAppender to write logs files per day in a remote server?

Comment: you have to do a little work here. There's plenty of information on the remoting appender, buffering appenders in general, and log file rolling. It's also hard to understand the question.

Comment: You could also use a regular RollingFileAppender but have the log file be on a network shared folder.